# WindowsAPICodePack property null when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-api-code-pack

When debugging locally I am able to read the Title from an .mp4 video.

However, after I have deployed this application to IIS, the Title property is null.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(videosLocation).GetFiles()
                            .Where(x => x.FullName.EndsWith(".mp4", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            .ToList())
        {
            using (var so = ShellObject.FromParsingName(f.FullName))
            {
                var titleProp = so.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Title).ValueAsObject;
                var title = titleProp == null ? "no title" : titleProp.ToString();
                // title is null when deployed
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster I have added the code in question